# Linux: How to allow group members to set/change permissions on a file

Tags: linux, permissions

I thought I had a good understanding of how permissions worked on linux.

I have folder where it and everything inside has the owner "me" and the group "group". I gave the group rwx access on all the files and still members of the group cannot modify permissions on any files.

I'm using Redhat Enterprise Linux 5

Is it possible to allow group members to modify permissions on file and not just the owner? How?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Only the owner and root can change the permissions of a file or directory in *nix.